# (postgreSQL 9.5) insert into table with date column using make_date oddity

Tags: postgresql

I've run into an oddity while combining insert, make_date and cases. I'm working on a postgre server with version 9.5.

Here's an abstract version of my code:

value is varchar and date is date.

```
INSERT INTO Table (value, date)
    SELECT othervalue,
         (SELECT MAKE_DATE (
             SELECT MIN(...),
             CASE
                 WHEN 1 THEN 0
                 WHEN 2 THEN 1
             END,1)) FROM OtherTable
    GROUP BY value
```

The SELECT section does its job correctly (returns value and a correctly constructed date)

EDIT: What I mean by this is that SELECT othervalue, (SELECT Make_Date(..)) works correctly when run. It's when INSERT INTO (SELECT othervalue, (SELECT Make_Date(..))) inserts the value, but null for date.

What is odd (to me) is that INSERT inserts NULL for date.

What is causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

May be it will work

```
INSERT INTO Table (value, date)
SELECT value,
     MAKE_DATE (
         SELECT MIN(...),
         CASE
             WHEN 1 THEN 0
             WHEN 2 THEN 1
         END,1)::timestamp FROM OtherTable
GROUP BY value
```

Comment: That changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO test_tbl (value, date) VALUES (
    (SELECT othervalue FROM OtherTable ORDER BY date LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT
         MAKE_DATE (
             SELECT MIN(...),
             CASE
                 WHEN 1 THEN 0
                 WHEN 2 THEN 1
             END,1) FROM OtherTable
    GROUP BY value))
```

Comment: I need to edit my first post better. I can't post the actual code, but my code doesn't select from the same table. Sorry for the ambiguity :/

Comment: Its fine, what is your code trying to do? Edited my post, not sure What your goal is, just guessin at this point.

Comment: My code is trying to insert a value and a date into an existing table. The date is built using Make_Date(int,int,int), where the ints are fetched via a CASE WHEN statement.